# Vertically aligning a label with PureLayout

Tags: ios, uiview, alignment, uilabel, pure-layout

I have a simple UIView subclass that contains a label. This subclass has the following init method:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 44)
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    self.addSubview(titleLabel)

    titleLabel.text = "Some text"
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()

    titleLabel.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Leading, withInset: 20)
    titleLabel.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Trailing, withInset: 20)
    titleLabel.autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis(.Horizontal)
}
```

Actually, the text of the label could change at runtime, but anyway, I don't see the label vertically centered within its parent view when I run the app... could somebody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is PureLayout? Is it any Auto layout library?

Comment: @BharatModi https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout

Answer (score 0):

See this, if it could help you,

```
let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

label.text = "Some dummy text"
self.view.addSubview(label)

let centreH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

let centreV = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

self.view.addConstraint(centreH)
self.view.addConstraint(centreV)
```